# PreparedStatement "eats" my line endings

Tags: java, mysql, sql, tomcat, prepared-statement

After that:

```
String content = "Some \n multiline \n content";
//actually, content comes from request (tomcat application)
stmnt.setString(2,content);
```

I has that in database (mysql):

> "Some multiline content"

How I can avoid that?

Part of page source:

```
<textarea name="content" rows="5" cols="40"># encoding: UTF-8def put_actions()action = "<a href='view'><img src=
```

but must be:

```
<textarea name="content" rows="5" cols="40"># encoding: UTF-8
def put_actions()
    action = "<a href='view'><img src=
```

PS. With just

```
statement = Connection.createStatement();
statement.executeUpdate("UPDATE v5_scriptlets SET content = '"+request.getParameter(request)+"'");
```

all works ok.

Comment: I think you *may* mis-understand what is happening.  How are you viewing that content?  It may be the viewer just not showing control codes, even if they *are* present in the database.  Query it using your application and check it in there.  Just in case.

Comment: in your internet explorer, "right click" the web page then click "view source". you will see the new lines are present.

Comment: Updated post. \n doesn't present in database. Checked thought mysql console client and page source.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, error was in my helper method, that removes all \n from string >_< Thanks all for help!